# ¿Como acceder a array que está dentro de una IIFE en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo acceder a un array que contiene otro array que se llama name que esta en un [IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) para que el usuario pueda ordenar la lista en javascript?

```js
(function(window) {
    // variables
    var sortName = document.getElementById("sortName");
    var bills = null;
    var name = null;
    var type = null;
    var date = null;
    var amount = null;
    var addForm = document.getElementById("addForm");

    function composeBill(bill) {
        // create elements
        var containerNewBill = document.createElement('div');
        var nameValue = document.createElement('p');
        var typeValue = document.createElement('p');
        var dateValue = document.createElement('p');
        var amountValue = document.createElement('p');

        //New class for the new bill
        containerNewBill.className = "containerNewBill";
        containerNewBill.classList.add('bill');

        // name, type, date and amount content text
        nameValue.innerText = bill.name;
        typeValue.innerText = bill.type;
        dateValue.innerText = bill.date;
        amountValue.innerText = bill.amount;

        // append the sub-elements
        containerNewBill.appendChild(nameValue);
        containerNewBill.appendChild(typeValue);
        containerNewBill.appendChild(dateValue);
        containerNewBill.appendChild(amountValue);

        // save the element reference on the note object, so in the future a DOM query is not required to access the element
        bill.element = containerNewBill;

        return containerNewBill;
    }

    function addBill() {
        // object of the new bill
        var newBill = {
            name: addForm.name.value,
            type: addForm.type.value,
            date: addForm.date.value,
            amount: addForm.amount.value
        };

        // reset form inputs
        addForm.name.value = '';
        addForm.type.value = '';
        addForm.date.value = '';
        addForm.amount.value = '';

        composeBill(newBill);

        // add the new note to the DOM
        container.appendChild(newBill.element);

        // add the new note into the notes array
        bills.push(newBill);
    }

    function renderBills() {
        container = document.getElementById('billnote');
        var billnote = bills.map(composeBill);

        // append each note
        billnote.forEach(function(bill) {
            container.appendChild(bill);
        });

        // on submit note form event
        addForm.addEventListener('submit', function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            addBill();
        });
    }

    function main(data) {

        if (data && Array.isArray(data)) {
            bills = data;
            return renderBills();
        }

        return new Error('Bills Array params required', bills);
    }

    function saveNote() {
        // updated bill data
        name = addForm.name.value;
        type = addForm.type.value;
        date = addForm.date.value;
        amount = addForm.amount.value;

        // update note DOM for title and content
        // request the title and content elements based on the tag name
        // this request type returns a HTML collection inste of a single node
        var name = element.getElementsByTagName('p');
        var type = element.getElementsByTagName('p');
        var date = element.getElementsByTagName('p');
        var amount = element.getElementsByTagName('p');

        // validate the DOM queries
        if (name) name[0].innerText = name // use index 0 because is a HTML collection (array-like)
        if (amount) amount[0].innerText = amount; // use index 0 because is a HTML collection (array-like)
    }

    window.app = {
        main: main,
    };

}(window));

var data = [{
    name: addForm.name.value,
    type: addForm.type.value,
    date: addForm.date.value,
    amount: addForm.amount.value
}];

app.main(data);
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el contexto? Esos datos los sacas de un formulario? si quieres enviar `data` a main, por que no usas `name: document.getElementById("addForm").name.value`? es muy confuso lo que quieres hacer si no lo explicas bien :P

Answer (score 0):

Siempre y cuando tengas acceso a la variable `window` o `global` en el scope actual:

```js
(function()
{
  console.debug(window);
  //console.debug(global);
  window.a = "hello world";
  //global.a; = "hello world";
})();

setTimeout(function()
{
  console.debug(window.a);
  //console.debug(global.a);
},1000);
```

**ES6**

```js
(() => {
  console.debug(window)
  //console.debug(global)
  window.a = "hello world";
 // global.a = "hello world";
})()

setTimeout(()=>
{
  console.debug(window.a);
  //console.debug(global.a);
},1000);
```